# Insert a few bytes to mySQL table -> 180kB written to disk

Tags: mysql, innodb

My RaspberryPi reads out a temperature/air pressure sensor every 5 minutes, and writes the data and a timestamp to a CSV file so far. Let it be about 25 bytes each time.

I'm also writing the data to a mySQL database (MariaDB, InnoDB) as kind of experiment, since this allows simple queries, data access from different processes, and so on. For faster access, the timestamp is a primary key.

In principle, the timestamp is 4 bytes, each value 4 byte float, so in total about 12 bytes. Of course, there are some more bytes for data organisation, but with `iotop -Pa`, I found out that every 5 minutes, about 180kB are written to disk. That is pretty much, even when considering journaling, and may be the timestamp being a primary key.

**Does anyone know what the DB is doing there? And may be, are there any tweaks to reduce this?**

I fear that data is overwritten again and again, and though the database resides on a USB flash drive instead of the internal SD card, this will wear out the drive quite fast. (Yes, I know, a DB on this kind of media is no good idea, but I didn't expect that it would be that worse)

Answer (score 1):

For every commit of a transaction, MySQL writes a record to the [InnoDB redo log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html). The write size is at least 512 bytes, even if the row size is smaller. You could reduce the writes by grouping your changes into transactions (see https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/10/08/measuring-the-amount-of-writes-in-innodb-redo-logs/).

You can also set MySQL to defer writing to the redo log file when you commit. This has a risk of losing data if your device crashes before the committed transaction reaches the disk.

MySQL might also write to its binary log, if you have that enabled (you probably don't on a device like this, but you should check).

When it comes time to flush changed pages from RAM to disk, first MySQL writes pages to the "doublewrite segment", then writes the real pages to their respective place on disk. This is to protect against crashes during a page write, which could corrupt your database. If you care more about reducing write I/O than the risk, you could disable the doublewrite activity (but don't complain later when your database is corrupted).

- Group changes into transactions
- Comment out `binlog`, if any is set
- `innodb_doublewrite=0`
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0`

See also http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/04/reducing-mysql-durability-for-testing.html